# Mostrar un mensaje con un array

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo una tabla que esta llena de información, antes de enviar una solicitud seleccione las filas que deseo enviar, cuando ya terminé de seleccionar las filas hago click en el boton enviar (se envía correctamente).

Lo que quiero es que cuando se envíen las filas salga un solo mensaje donde me indique los documentos que se han enviado, he estado intentando con el siguiente código pero me sale un mensaje de envío por separado y no me sale un solo mensaje que me indique los documentos que se han enviado.

```
public static String[] documentos;

protected void btnEnviarActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int[] selectedRow = tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRows();
        int i = tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRow();
        if (i == -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione los documentos que desea solicitar"); 
        }
        else{
            for(int t : selectedRow){
                String codArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 0);
                String codCentroCosto = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 1);
                String tipoArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 4);
                String doc = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 6).toString().trim();
                String nivelArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 7);
                String lote = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 9);
                String fila = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 10);
                String usuarioSolicita = Constante.idUsuario;
                Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getSelectedItem();
                String centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
                String centroCostoOrigen = Constante.c_ccosto;
                if (centroCostoDestino.equals("0")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione el Destino del Documento","Alerta",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    cboCentroCostoDestino.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    MovimientoArchivoDTO m = new MovimientoArchivoDTO();
                    m.setC_c_archivo(codArchivo);
                    CentroCostoDTO c = new CentroCostoDTO();
                    c.setC_ccosto(codCentroCosto);
                    m.setC_ccosto(c);
                    m.setC_ccosto_origen(centroCostoOrigen);
                    m.setC_ccosto_destino(centroCostoDestino);
                    m.setC_tipo_doc(tipoArchivo);
                    m.setC_t_doc(doc);
                    m.setC_c_nivel_archivo(nivelArchivo);
                    m.setLote(lote);
                    m.setFila(fila);
                    m.setC_c_usuario_solicita(usuarioSolicita);
                    int estado = x.RegistrarSolicitud_SA(m);
                    if (estado == 1){
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se mandó el Documento:"+" "+doc);
                        documentos = doc.split(" ");
                        String notificacion = "Se mandaron los siguientes documentos:\n";
                        for (String value : documentos) {
                            notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + "\n";
                            System.out.println(value);
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] { notificacion }, "Solicitud Enviada", 1, null);
                    }
                    else
                        mensaje("Error en enviar");
                    }
            }
            ListarDocumentoSA(estado_flg);
        }
    }
```

Estas imagenes son los mensajes que me salen por cada documento que se ha enviado, pero lo que quiero es que salga en un solo mensaje los documentos que se han enviado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58854/discussion-on-question-by-angelica-mostrar-un-mensaje-con-un-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPADTE 3:

Aunque ya le funciona con el UPDATE 2, para ajustarnos al titulo usted podria usar:

`Arrays.toString(documentos)` en

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] { Arrays.toString(documentos) }, "Solicitud Enviada", 1, null);
```

para convertirlo en un string, pero creo que no le funcionaria como ahora entre otras porque no se añade los nuevos valores.

pues usted hace esto `documentos = doc.split(" ");`

si quiere usar esto del `Arrays.toString()` tendria que tabajar esa parte.

---

Por otra parte por curiosidad si el tipo de array es bidimencional por ejemplo, usted puede hacer uso de [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] ar_bid = new int[2][2];

        ar_bid[0][0] = 1;
        ar_bid[0][1] = 2;
        ar_bid[1][0] = 3;
        ar_bid[1][1] = 4;


        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ar_bid));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar_bid));
    }
}
```

`Arrays.toString()` funciona bien para las arrays unidimensionales, pero no funciona bien para matrices multidimensionales.

lo anterior tendria una salida mas o menos asi

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[I@677327b6, [I@14ae5a5]
```

> UPADTE 2:

Le muestra varia ventanas pienso que porque esta iterenado
dentro de

`for(int t : selectedRow){`

y si `estado == 1`

```
int estado = x.RegistrarSolicitud_SA(m);
    if (estado == 1){

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] { notificacion }, "Solicitud Enviada", 1, null);
    }
```

mire sacandola fuera del if- iteracion incial esta linea `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog...` comentela o algo la que esta dentro del for donde se iteran los datos sobre documentos, y añada algo asi:

```
    //..
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] { sb.toString() }, "Solicitud Enviada", 1, null);
    ListarDocumentoSA(estado_flg); //encima de esta
```

esa parte del codigo que estamos usando.

> UPDATE:

Trate lo siguiente:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String notificacion = "Se mandaron los siguientes documentos:\n";
    sb.append(notificacion + "-")

    for (String value : documentos) {
       notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + "\n";

       //si solo quiere el value
       sb.append(value + "  \n");

       //si quiere tambien el valor de notificacion como tiene arriba
       //elinimar el anterior -> sb.append(value + "  \n"); anterior
       //y usar el siguiente: solo tiene que descomentarlo

       //sb.append(notificacion);
    }

    //System.out.println(sb.toString());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] { sb.toString() }, "Solicitud Enviada", 1, null);
```

---

> ANTIGUO:

No entiendo bien su pregunta:

usted dice: *..me sale un mensaje con el primer documento que se envió, luego otro mensaje con el otro documento que se envio y asi...*

Me imagino que se refiere a esta parte del codigo:

```
for (String value : documentos) {
   notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + "\n";
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

supongo que lo que quiere enviar esta en `value` y lo que usted obtiene es lo que quiere pero esta linea por linea por esto `System.out.println(value);`

---

Entoces si entendi bien puede hacerlo de varias formas usando:

```
System.out.print(value);

for (String value : documentos) {
   notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + "\n";
   System.out.print(value + " ");
}
```

o de esta otra manera:

```
String temp_value;

for (String value : documentos) {
   notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + "\n";

   //usamos += para concatenar el texto
   //pero tengo la duda de si lo que quiere mostar es notificacion o value yo se lo dejo con value porque usted comento que se lo mostraba bien pero por filas, quizas tenga que usar temp_value += value + " "; para dar un espacio.
   temp_value += value; 
}

System.out.println(temp_value);
```

---

por otro lado quizas podria usar la clase [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String value : documentos) {
   notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + "\n";

   sb.append(value + " "); 
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

---

**P.D:** *era muy largo para un comentario, si no esto, puede comentarme y modificar su pregunta añadiendo un ejemplo de la salida que espera.*

Comment: lo que quiero mostrar en el mensaje son los documentos que he enviado, pero me sale por separado, osea en el primer mensaje me sale "Se envio el documento: doc1", luego se abre otro mensaje diciendo que se envio el segundo mensaje, y quiero que se muestre en uno solo

Comment: @Angelica pero el segundo mensaje tambien dice  "Se envio el documento: doc2" o solo muestra el value, si es lo segundo es muy posible que el codigo anterior le funcione, si le muestra digamos la cabecera en cada mensaje algo asi "Se envio el documento: doc2" y usted lo que quiere es que se muestre solo "doc2" siguiendo la logica del `String temp_value` o del `StringBuldier sb`, podria declararlas como globales y en cada iterecion añadir los datos al `sb` sin imprimirlos y cuando esten todos los datos mandar a imprimir es `sb.toString()` desde el lugar que quiera al terminar de añadir .Saludos

Comment: @Angelica por su com me imagino que esta imprimiendo asi `System.out.println(notificacion);` y no con `System.out.println(value);` quizas sea un error de typo porque si no, no se de donde sale que le muestre -> "Se mandaron los siguientes documentos:" .Saludos P.D: cuando dije global puede ser tambien ampliar el scope lo podria poner al comienzo del metodo si el metodo solo se ejecuta una vez, pero si solo se ejecuta una vez pienso que los codigos anteriores le podrian funcionar. si el metodo se usa varias veces para recolectar la info. puede hacerlas globales y usar otro metodo para imprimir.

Comment: Edite mi pregunta para que sea mas entendible a lo que quiero llegar